# Mule ESB: XML to Map Conversion failure

Tags: mule

I have messages in my JMS topic that I want to read off & use a Mule JDBC Database adapter to store in a table ,I understand that I have to convert the JMS XML messages to a map payload for easily putting it in JDBC.Here is the sample flow:

```
<flow name="DBLoggerFlow">
  <jms:inbound-endpoint topic="${topic.logTopic}"
         connector-ref="jmsConnector" doc:name="JMS">
    <jms:transaction action="NONE" timeout="${queue.transaction.timeout}" />
  </jms:inbound-endpoint>
  <jdbc:xml-to-maps-transformer name="XMLToMaps"/>
  <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="insertion"
           connector-ref="insertionConnector"/>
</flow>
```

However I get this error when I run the code:

```
ERROR 2013-02-01 13:00:26,427 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jdbc:xml-to-maps-transformer'. One of ' is expected.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
```

Why is the XML to Map conversion a problem here? Is there an alternative or better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is the XML to Map conversion a problem here?

The `xml-to-maps-transformer` is available with Mule Entreprise Edition only: you're probably running on CE.

> Is there an alternative or better way of doing this?

Use MEL `xpath()` expressions in your JDBC statement to directly retrieve values from the XML payload and passing them to the DB.

Read the MEL Cheat Sheet for syntax info: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/refcard-mel.pdf

Comment: Hello David, for the purposes of a proof of concept I was trying a simple use case of reading messages from a topic & putting them into a database using JDBC connector. Here is the code:

Comment: Comments are not the place to share config. Accept my answer and open a new question with the config.